# Loop through each element and use the element as the output column name in GBM

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list of parameters in gbm and generate a dataframe that records results of each parameter combination.

Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import pandas as pd

totalreturn_annual = []
params = {'n_estimators': [1, 10, 50, 100, 200], 'max_depth': [1,3,5,7,9],
        'learning_rate': [0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3], 'min_samples_split ':[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9]}

params = pd.Dataframe(params)

for p in range(16):

        model_cape = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state = 10, max_features = 'sqrt',
                                               n_estimators = params.iloc[p,0], learning_rate = params.iloc[p,2], 
                                            alpha = params.iloc[p,3], max_depth = params.iloc[p,1],).fit(xs, ys_cape)
totalreturn_annual[p] = np.append(totalreturn_annual, totalreturn_annual_temp)
```

This is the error that I got:

```
    totalreturn_annual[p] = totalreturn_annual.append(totalreturn_annual)

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I wonder why I got the error.

Comment: `totalreturn_annual` is empty. You're trying to assign the result of `np.append` to a position in it that doesn't exist. You probably want `totalreturn_annual.append(...)`.

Comment: Can we do such kind of indexing  (totalreturn_annual[p] ) in the list? I know we can do this in the dictionary. When I try to test it, I get the same error. Any views from experts? I guess if you remove [p] from the left side it works?

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `totalreturn_annual` as an empty list in the first line of your code, thus it will not take an index.  This is resulting in the index error.  This should work:

```
np.append(totalreturn_annual, totalreturn_annual_temp)
```

instead of:

```
totalreturn_annual[p] = np.append(totalreturn_annual, totalreturn_annual_temp)
```

The np.append(a,b) function appends b to a; a is modified in place.